# NavBar aaprece fuera del contenido en dispositivos mobiles

Tags: reactjs

Estoy desarrollando una web para inmobiliaria con React, y el caso es que en dispositivos mobiles el menu debe aparecer al hacer click en el icono (tres rayas), en las pc se ven los titulos uno al lado del otro. el sitio es: https://inmobiliarianormaperez.com/inicio

Y tengo el siguiente componente:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { NavComponent } from './NavBar';

const SmallScreensNavbar = () =>{
// declare 'translate' as a state variable
let [translate, setTranslate ] = useState(true);
return(
    <div> 
         <button className="hamburger-btn"
                 onClick= {()=> setTranslate(!translate)}>  {/* toggle translate */}
              {/* change the btn text based on whether translate is true or false */} 
             {translate?<span>&#9776;</span>:<span>&times;</span>}
         </button>
         {/*hide and show the sidebar list based on whether translate is true or 
 false*/}
         <div id="sidebar-list" className={`${translate? "addTransiton": 
"removeTransition"}`}>
            <NavComponent
                navClass="nav-small"
                linkClassName = "nav-small-link"
                onClick = {()=>setTranslate(true)}  //set translate to true to hide the 
sidebar list
            />
         </div>
    </div>
    )
}
export default SmallScreensNavbar;
```

como veran le paso los miembros del menu. En css tengo:

```
.hamburger-btn{
font-size: 1.3rem;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 40px;
height: 35px;
right: 30px;
outline: none;
background-color: rgb(134, 125, 125);
color: whitesmoke;
}
.addTransiton{
 transform: translateX(170px);
 transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
 }
.removeTransition{
transform: translateX(20px);
transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
 }

#sidebar-list{
 background-color: rgb(134, 125, 125);
 height: 90vh;
 width: 170px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2000;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 margin-top: 70px;
}
```

Me gustaria que el menu aparezca dentro del sitio.